# Can I use an already-existing VM as docker-machine?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtualbox, docker-machine

**When I am in my virtualbox vm, can I use it as a target for docker-machine?**

For example, if I define some variables on it like;

```
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=example-machine
export DOCKER_HOST=localhost
```

etc. then use it like,

```
eval $(docker-machine env localhost)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use generic driver to attach to existing VM

```
docker-machine create -d generic --generic-ip-address <ip> --generic-ssh-key <keypath> --generic-ssh-user <user> --generic-ssh-port 22 <vm name>
```